# Managing website content

Tags: content-management-system, orchardcms

I just started developing my first website for a client using ASP.net and I've been thinking about this a lot, the client want to update certain parts of the website like images and add/remove offers and deals (mainly just text), so at first I thought of building a control panel he could use to control the content then I read about CMS and I got confused, what do you think is best and why?
I'm a quick learner, just need to know the best approach to take in this situation.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your client wants to regularly update large sections of website content, I would suggest using one of the open source CMS systems available.

This will save you a large amount of time as it will manage all the CRUD (create, update, delete) content operations which you'd otherwise have to wire up manually in your control panel. I know you've listed OrchardCMS however [Umbraco](https://umbraco.com/) is another good and easy to use option if you're targeting ASP.NET.

Most CMS systems will also provide a number of other useful features like

- Content editor Authentication
- Content versioning
- Content authorisation
- WSIWYG editor
- Add-on packages which allow content editors to easily create tables, forms, graphs, image galleries etc
- Cloud integration to simplify deployment

On the other hand, if your client only needs to update a small amount of website content on an infrequent basis, it may be simpler to create a basic control panel. It's also a good learning experience for you personally but this depends on whether you're interesting in building a collection of essentially CRUD forms. If the website grew or your client wanted more flexibility in the future, at this point you could look at integrating a CMS.

Another option you may not have considered is the headless CMS approach. These are normally paid services which host the CMS interface for you and provide you access over an API. A good example which I know has an ASP.NET SDK available is [Contentful](https://www.contentful.com/).

Comment: Thank you so much this will help me a lot, I think I'll choose the control panel option since it is a small amount of data that won't be updated frequently. One more question though, when wiring my control panel i'll have to add login mechanism so he/she could login as admin, right??  just to be clear here that there are no other approaches

Comment: Happy to help :) If you build your own control panel then yes, you will need some sort of authentication. There are a few plug + play options which may make your life easier such as https://auth0.com/ or https://firebase.google.com/products/auth/

Comment: GREAT!! Thanks a lot :)